# PHP re-posting data

Tags: php, post, curl

I receive data posted to a url on my domain, check it for certain field values, update a database if necessary and then post the received data onto another url.

Unfortunately the url (https) I'm posting to doesn't have a testbed or anything like that so I need to ensure that what I'm reposting is as it was received.

Does this look like it's a reasonable approach?

Thanks

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$fields_string = substr_replace($fields_string, "", -1);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://anotherdomain.com/script.php");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );    
curl_close($ch);    

$fh = fopen('audit.log', 'a');
fwrite($fh, $response."\r\n");
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can take `array` directly

This would work just fine:

```
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

You also need to manage multiple attempts in case the server is down .....